# Pronunciation rules

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, rules

I was always wondering if there is a compact set of rules that helps readers enunciate English words.

One of the reasons why I believe there are such rules is that there are some online dictionaries with pronunciation guides.

Comment: I would have thought an online dictionary for example saying *tough*, *though*, *through* and *thorough* are pronounced /tʌf/, /ðəʊ/, /θruː/ and  /ˈθʌrə/ respectively was an indication that the relationship between English orthography and pronunciation can be complicated and that the spelling often does not indicate the sounds of words.

Comment: @Henry: And *bough* and *cough* and... (See http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html for more!)

Comment: You could always memorize [The Chaos](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some online dictionaries have a vocal feature.  That does not demonstrate that there are rules, it only shows that every word has a fairly uniform pronunciation in a country (with certain regional variations.)

English spelling often bears little resemblance to pronunciation. There are dozens of "rules", and thousands of exceptions. Sorry.

You can try to learn the *usual* pronunciations of a particular group of letters, but there may be several (as noted in the "ough" examples from commenters (compare *tough, though, through, slough, bough, bought, cough, hiccough*).  *Slough*, for example, is two words with different pronunciations and meanings.  Likewise for *lead* and *wind*.

So for many (if not most) English words, learning how to say it and learning how to spell it are two distinct tasks.  Completely unlike,  say, Japanese or Spanish, where  orthography maps perfectly to orthoepy.

Learn to spell the words you use; eventually you will be able to guess pronunciation of words you haven't used.

Comment: ***Japanese?*** I assume you're talking about hiragana and katakana and not kanji.

Comment: Definitely. It takes a phonetic alphabet for the concept of spelling vs prononunciation to even exist. I don't know any Japanese, but all of it I have ever seen transliterated is transparently pronounceable, knowing Spanish pronunciation (with only a few extra consonants such as "tsu", and the "w", which Spanish doesn't exactly have).